# Separate array line by line

Tags: javascript, arrays, cheerio

I scrape info from webpage and I want to push them to array in order to use them later. But when I try to reach 1st, 2nd etc... item, instead of the word I got back only a character.

```
var arrType = [];    
            $('[name="type"]> option').each(function () {    
                arrType.push($(this).text());    
            });    
const vehicleType = arrType.join(", ");
```

If I print the vehicleType then I got something what is looks like array (also the typeof is array), but when I want to print out vehicleType[0] I just get back one character.

```
console.log (vehicleType)
[text1,text2,text3]

console.log (vehicleType[0])
t
```

Comment: _"The [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) method creates and **returns a new string** by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string."_

Comment: Don't call `.join()` when you don't want the elements of the array as one big string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can reduce your code a bit. You can define your variable at the same time you pull the option text by using `.map()` instead of `.each()`.

```js
var arrType = $('[name="type"]> option').map(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim();
}).toArray();
```

Second, to target the first item of the array, don't use `.join()` at all.

```js
console.log(arrType[0]);
```